# Java - Basic, How do I get a custom colour working?

Tags: java, colors

I know this is simple to do but for some reason I can't get it working.  I'm trying to create a custom colour in Java and it doesn't seem to be working.

```
import java.awt.Color;

Color deepGreen = new Color(34, 139, 34);
bar.changeColour(Color.deepGreen);
```

I've googled it and I can't work it out, sorry if I'm being dense.

Comment: It should be 
`bar.changeColour(deepGreen);`

Comment: I've tried that and no luck

Comment: Then `changeColour` doesn't accept a `Color` object as parameter.

Comment: What is the type of `bar` and what is the `changeColour` method ?

Comment: So I can't use a custom color?  `changeColour` & `bar` are part of a external class

Comment: @FinishLine Yes you can if the `changeColour` accept a `Color` object as parameter. If it's the case, you should provide more informations about what does not work. Compile errors ? Runtime errors ? What is `bar` ? What does `changeColour` does exactly ?

Comment: The solution to your problem is in the `changeColour` method (and any other class it uses. You mention a `Colour` class below, it's probably relevant too). Show us the information we ask for or we can't help you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "not working" do you mean it says `deepGreen` cannot be resolved? You should have

```
bar.changeColour(deepGreen);
```

instead of

```
bar.changeColour(Color.deepGreen);
```

`deepGreen` is a variable you have just defined, not one of the Color constants.

This is assuming `changeColor()` accepts a `Color` as an argument.

Comment: `The method changeColour(Colour) in the type Bar is not applicable for the arguments (Color) `is the error I get.  I'm using an external class for it so I'm assumming it won't let me use a custom colour.

Comment: @FinishLine It means that `changeColour` accept an Object of type `Colour` (not `Color`). So you should create a `Colour` object.

Comment: Do you have a custom class called `Colour` that is different from `java.awt.Color`? your `changeColour()` method seems to take a parameter of type Colour, while you are trying to give it a Color. Those are different.

Comment: @ZouZOu I've played around with trying to create a `Colour` object, without any luck. 

@gla3dr Yes I do, I wasn't aware that it would affect the use of a custom colour

Comment: @FinishLine It doesn't affect the use of `java.awt.Color`. The argument to your `changeColour()` method must be of type `Colour`, going by the error you are getting. In your original example, you are trying to pass it an argument of type `java.awt.Color`. If you want to pass a `java.awt.Color` to changeColor(), then you will have to change the method to accept that type.